# RESTRICT_SYSLOG warning in csf cpanel plugin

Tags: linux, firewall

I could  see the following warning on top my `CSF WHM` plugin.

```
WARNING: RESTRICT_SYSLOG is disabled. See SECURITY WARNING in Firewall Configuration
```

Also I am getting the following error while checking the `watch system log`

```
Executable [] invalid
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could fix this issue by forced an update of CSF, so  the configuration includes the newer binary command locations.